# Improve Python scraping code with multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a simple python crawler using urllib2, bsoup, csv... (Python 2.7)
I have a .csv file where are stored url links which needs to be scraped.

From the code below, I am crawling specific number from links where it's finding maximum one of attenders from the website and `crawl(url)` function is working properly just like whole code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, csv, urllib2, urllib, re, time, lxml

def crawl(url):
    request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"})
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    readd = response.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(readd, "lxml")
    response.close()
    maxx = 0
    if (soup.find("div", attrs={"class" : "attendees-placeholder placeholder"})):
        exists = soup.find("div", attrs={"class" : "attendees-placeholder placeholder"})
        nmb = exists.find("ul", "user-list")
        numbe = nmb.find_all("li")
        number = len(numbe)
        if (number > maxx):
            maxx = number
    else:
        number = 0

    print maxx



urls = csv.reader(open('all_links_2017.csv'))


for url in urls:
    crawl(url[0])
```

Meanwhile, it's going too slow because I have around 100000 urls.
I have tried many multithreading samples but it was not what I expected.
Is there any way to improve this code so it can go faster? (i.e. multithreading, pool...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you've tried?:

```
import threading

def crawl(url, sem):
    # Semaphore grabs a thread
    sem.acquire(blocking=False)
    # Your code here
    .
    .
    .
    # All the work is done (i.e. after print maxx)
    sem.release() 

sem = threading.Semaphore(4)
threads = [threading.Thread(target=crawl, args=(url, sem, )) for url in urls]

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()
```

Edit: Changed first `for` to list comprehension.

Edit: Added `threading.Semaphore()` limiting method. A Semaphore is a limiter (in essence its a counter of threads) to keep track of the number of threads running concurrently. In this case, the value is set to a maximum of 4 threads at any given time. This can also be used with the `with` context manager if you chose to use a `BoundedSemaphore()`.

Comment: It automatically gives me error: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/urosv/Desktop/Conferences project - 30/thread_test.py", line 32, in <module>
    thread.start()
error: can't start new thread

Comment: This edit works perfectly, the only one problem is that remote server blocks connection because it detects robot, is there any solution to avoid it?

Comment: @RolandSmith The level of security the server had was unbeknownst to us. I send upwards of 12 sets of 20K queries in parallel each day. Servers I interface with aren't smart enough for the kind of detection the OP encountered.

Comment: @U.J.V. Please see my update showing use of the `threading.Semaphore()` method. It limits the number of active threads executing `crawl()` at any one time.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `multiprocessing.Pool`. Change `crawl` to *return* `maxx` instead of print it. Then use the `multiprocessing.Pool.imap_unordered` method.

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
urls = csv.reader(open('all_links_2017.csv'))
for value in p.imap_unordered(crawl, [u[0] for u in urls]):
    print(value)
```

By default, this will create as many worker processes as your CPU has cores.

Comment: multiprocessing seems heavy for simple IO, how about `from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool` so still using threads?

Comment: Given the heavy use of 'soup, threads might well run into GIL issues. Since the data flow from between parent and workers is pretty light, a proper Pool seems appropriate.

Comment: @RolandSmith I changed return value from crawl, imported code as yours and it doesn't prints anything.